# Difference between DVD-R and DVD+R discs

Tags: dvd, disc

What is the difference between DVD-R and DVD+R discs?

I usually buy DVD+R just because it's a plus. Does it make difference for archivists? The price is *almost* the same for both formats.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In prior readings, and analysis that I've read, DVD-R has a GREATER compatibility than DVD+R - for example, on older DVD Players (for example, 2004 and earlier), DVD-R would work in 90% of systems whereas DVD+R would work in 80%. (These are numbers from memory and could be off, but I'm 99% certain that -R was MORE compatible than +R.)

In addition, -R has 6.625 MiB more usable space. See: http://www.videohelp.com/dvd

Comment: This information is really interesting and useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

From [About.com](http://netforbeginners.about.com/cs/multimedia/a/DVD_explained_2.htm):

> **Standards Differences**
>
> 1) The DVD-R (pronounced "DVD dash R")
>   and -RW media formats are officially
>   approved by the standards group DVD
>   Forum. The DVD Forum was founded by
>   Mitsubishi, Sony, Hitachi, and Time
>   Warner, so it has tremendous industry
>   support for its technical standards.
>
> 2) DVD+R ("DVD plus” R) and +RW
>   formats are not approved by the DVD
>   Forum standards group, but are instead
>   supported by the DVD+RW Alliance. The
>   DVD+RW Alliance is supported by Sony,
>   Yamaha, Philips, Dell, and JP, so it
>   also has tremendous industry support
>   for its technical standards. Note that
>   Sony supports both organizations.
>
> **Technical Differences**
>
> The main functional differences
>   between DVD-R and DVD+R are:
>
> 1) the
>   DVD recorder's built-in defects
>   management
>
> 2) the way the recorders
>   format and rewrite DVDs
>
> 3) the price.

Comment: DVD6C officially accepted DVD+R and DVD+RW on Jan 25 2008. see wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD%2BR

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that DVD+ is the better system, especially now that virtually all drives will handle both media.

http://www.cdfreaks.com/article/203-Why-DVDRW-is-superior-to-DVD-RW/

Comment: An old but very informative article. Thanks!

Comment: That article is highly relevant, but please avoid link-only answers.

Comment: Read the dates.

Answer (score 2):

Um... just because there's a "+" in the name doesn't make it better.
Read Wikipedia ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_formats)) for a simple explanation:

> Recordable format compatibility
>
> DVD drives from 2004 should be able to
>   read either of the competing
>   recordable formats, older drives may
>   favour DVD-R discs. Modern drives
>   (certainly at time of writing in 2007)
>   typically allow writing to both
>   DVD-R[W] and DVD+R[W] discs making the
>   difference largely irrelevant to the
>   average consumer.
>
> DVD-R for Authoring: a special-purpose
>   DVD-R used to record DVD masters,
>   which can then be duplicated to
>   pressed DVDs by a duplication plant.
>   They require a special DVD-R recorder,
>   and are not often used nowadays since
>   many duplicators can now accept
>   ordinary DVD-R masters.
>
> DVD-R (strictly DVD-R for General):
>   can record up to 4.7 GB in a similar
>   fashion to a CD-R disc. Once recorded
>   and finalized it can be played by most
>   DVD-ROM players.
>
> DVD+R: can record up to 4.7 GB
>   single-layered/single-sided DVD+R
>   disc, at up to 16x speed. Like DVD-R
>   you can record only once.